# Send e-mail to a customer with Google Sheets when cell changes

Tags: google-sheets

I want Google Sheets to automatically send an email to a customer when his order Status changes.

How can I achieve that?

[The table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlWR0.jpg)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your goal and your current issue of your script from `I want Google Sheets to automatically send an email to a customer when his order Status changes. How can I achieve that?`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal? If you can do, can you provide your current script? By this, it will help users think of your issue and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, or write a script that triggers a mail-merge add-on
https://zapier.com/apps/gmail/integrations/google-sheets/144/send-emails-via-gmail-when-google-sheets-rows-are-updated